# Vue with binded aria-hidden

Tags: data-binding, vuejs2, wai-aria

I want to show a modal with vue.
with `aria-hidden="false"` it should be visible.

I added this snippet with a v-bind `:aria-hidden="modalHidden"` to the div and set it to false by default (for testing purpose only):

```
created() {
        this.modalHidden = false;
    },
```

- but this attribute is only in the DOM when it's != false.
  is there any possibility to set this value to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use data to change bind value. For example:

```
:aria-hidden="[!isVisible]"
```

```
data() {
 return {
   isVisible: false
 };
}
```

After that you can change value at any stage of the component:

```
// mounted
mounted() {
 this.isVisible = true
},
// or event 
methods: {
 onClickEvent() {
   this.isVisible = !this.isVisible
 }
}
```

I hope this will help you.